# Can a Temple of the Sun God be moved?

Tags: bloons-td-5

I haven't unlocked the helicopter monkey's final upgrade yet, so I can't test this:

I saw a video where someone had multiple TSGs side by side, which is normally impossible because of the sacrifices. Can the helicopter re-locate TSGs?

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that the Temple of the Sun God can not be moved by the Helicopter's "move a tower" ability (I just tested it out in Sandbox mode). You can refer to @ChaseC's answer to see how to get two Temple of the Sun God's near each other.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so, but there is a way to get 2 TSG's relatively close.

Step 1: Place super monkey

[image]

Step 2: Upgrade super monkey into a TSG

[image]

Step 3: Place second super monkey as close as possible. Don't let the range cover the first TSG. You can see how close you can get here.

[image]

Step 4: This is the important part. Make sure you upgrade to a TSG BEFORE you do the range upgrade. That way, the range will not cover the first TSG and you won't have to sacrifice the first one.

[image]